# Overloading the Main thread

Tags: android, multithreading

In one activity of my app I make a bunch of edit text fields dynamically and then set them with some text from sharedpreferences. I realise that this is a bit much for the main thread to handle which is why there is some lagging of the app when it loads. I am quite new to the concept of threads so I was wondering what the best way was to put the loading of the strings from sharedpreferences into another thread and then just display a loading bar(or similar) in the meantime(in the main thread I guess). Please explain in great detail because threads are new to me.

Also if there are any tutorials on this that point me the the right direction they would also be useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: only main thread can change UI, so in your case you can have sharedpreference code in new thread, [reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads)

Comment: Ok thankyou, will modify the question a wee bit then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsyncTask is what you need.
Create a class that extends AsyncTask
Do your heavy work in doInBackground() 
Example:

```
 Class Example extends AsyncTask{
    @Override 
    protected void doInBackground(Object... args){
        //do ur stuff
    }
    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(Object arg){
        //do what you wanna do after doInBackground
    }
 }
```

Call your task by new Example().execute();

Answer (score 1):

Whilst only the main thread can make changes to the UI, you can you the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class to do all the other work on another thread and then push things to the main thread as they are ready to be put on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can have something like this: Just to guide you

```
final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Title", "Loading");
                            new Thread(new Runnable()
                                {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run()
                                        {
                                            //get data from shared preferences 

                                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                                                {

                                                    @Override
                                                    public void run()
                                                        {
                                                            pd.dismiss();
                                                            //set that text to your dynamic textview

                                                        }
                                                });

                                        }
                                }).start();
```